# How to add an already installed Linux to Windows boot loader?

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, grub, bootloader

Is there anyway to add an already installed Linux(preferably Kali Linux) to windows boot loader?
I had both Windows and Kali working fine using GRUB boot loader. After my windows got corrupted and I was forced to reinstall my windows, I lost GRUB and Kali along the way. Now my PC automatically boots to windows and there is no sign of GRUB or Kali. Of course I still can access Kali using boot menu but as you know it is not very pleasant. So if you guys know anyway to add Kali to Windows boot menu or install GRUB and add windows and Kali to it, please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to add an already installed Linux to Windows boot loader?

Windows bootloader supports Windows only. Different or similar Windows versions can be added but not other OSes. What you're asking is not possible.

For your dual-boot you need to use Grub.

1. Change UEFI settings to boot from Kali instead of Windows and boot Kali.
2. Run `sudo update-grub` in terminal and reboot.

You should now be presented with a Grub menu that includes both Kali and Windows. This does not prevent booting Windows from the UEFI menu as you've been doing.

**Your current workflow is**

```
UEFI -> Windows
```

or

```
UEFI -> Grub -> KaliOS
```

**You new workflow will be**

```
UEFI -> Grub -> KaliOS / Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

Boit your Kali installation via the UEFI/BIOS menu and reinstall GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Kali Linux

Open terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

Type password and press ENTER.